# Powerbeats3 Bluetooth Nightmare

Tags: bluetooth

I've been trying to get this *!&(@)&#$*^@%& thing connected for about a month and it's honestly driving me crazy. I finally got it working, then restarted and now, it's just broken again.

- Ubuntu 17.04
- Killer AC 1535 Wifi/Bluetooth
- Blueman 2.0.4

`systemctl status bluetooth`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-05-16 21:38:01 EDT; 13s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 4810 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─4810 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Starting SDP server
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Sap driver initialization failed.
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

It seems as though I can pair without issue, but connecting is immediately declined.

`sudo bluetoothctl`

```
[bluetooth]# pair 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF 
Attempting to pair with 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF UUIDs: 74ec2172-0bad-4d01-8f77-997b2be0722a
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF 
Attempting to connect to 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Following some instructions on arch wiki, I tried to get some more debug info:

`systemctl status bluetooth`

```
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Starting SDP server
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: Sap driver initialization failed.
May 16 21:38:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
May 16 21:41:14 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF: Protocol not available
May 16 21:42:45 brandon-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[4810]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF: Protocol not available
```

`journalctl -n 20`

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2017-05-16 21:28:33 EDT, end at Tue 2017-05-16 21:45:01 EDT. --
May 16 21:44:48 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 97967
May 16 21:44:48 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (979735) is greater than comparison timestamp (979734).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:48 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 97973
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (981071) is greater than comparison timestamp (981065).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 98107
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (981102) is greater than comparison timestamp (981096).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 98110
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (981132) is greater than comparison timestamp (981126).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 98113
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (981162) is greater than comparison timestamp (981156).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 98116
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (981252) is greater than comparison timestamp (981248).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 98125
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (981282) is greater than comparison timestamp (981278).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 98128
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (981313) is greater than comparison timestamp (981308).  This most likely re
May 16 21:44:50 brandon-XPS-15-9560 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1364]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (Powerbeats) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 98131
May 16 21:45:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 CRON[5125]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 16 21:45:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 CRON[5126]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 16 21:45:01 brandon-XPS-15-9560 CRON[5125]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 1):

The following finally worked:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
$ sudo bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 9C:B6:D0:DF:14:76 brandon-XPS-15-9560 [default]
[NEW] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF Powerbeats³
[NEW] Device 00:1F:FF:3F:BA:51 PR BT 6654
[bluetooth]# connect 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF 
Attempting to connect to 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]# quit
[DEL] Controller 9C:B6:D0:DF:14:76 brandon-XPS-15-9560 [default]
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
18
$ sudo bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 9C:B6:D0:DF:14:76 brandon-XPS-15-9560 [default]
[NEW] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF Powerbeats³
[NEW] Device 00:1F:FF:3F:BA:51 PR BT 6654
[bluetooth]# connect 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF 
Attempting to connect to 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:DA:A8:BF ServicesResolved: yes
```

Yay!